# Creating an instance of a class when running a file in embedded python in C++

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to create an instance of a python class when calling a script from embedded python -

```
Py_Initialize();

object main_module = import("__main__");
object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

std::string fileName = "D:/Dog.py";
const char *f = fileName.c_str();

PyObject *obj = Py_BuildValue("s", "D:/dog.py");
FILE *file = _Py_fopen(f, "r+");    

if (file != NULL)
{    
   PyObject* result = PyRun_File(file, f, Py_file_input, main_namespace.ptr(), main_namespace.ptr());
}
```

My Dog.py file looks like this -

```
import sys
import os
import Cat

class Dog:
   def __init__(self):
        print("I am a dog!")
        self.cat = Cat()

def main():
    """ main function """
    print("\nStart...")
    dog = Dog()

    return 0

#### --Main-- ####
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My Cat.py file looks like this -

```
import sys
import os

class Cat:
   def __init__(self):
        print("I am a cat!")

def main():
    """ main function """
    print("\nStart...")
    cat = Cat()

    return 0

#### --Main-- ####
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code crashes with some python errors. If the Dog class does not instantiate Cat, then the code executes successfully. What should I do to instantiate the Cat class without any errors?

Comment: In `Dog.py`, you don't import `Cat.py`. How is the `Dog` class supposed to know where to find the `Cat` class? (Leaving aside the question why a dog would want to instantiate a cat in the first place...)

Comment: @Seb Sorry, forgot to add it, but the issue is still there

Comment: @Scheff Locating Cat.py isnt the problem, since if I comment the line "self.cat = Cat() ", the code works fine. I have also added D:\ to system path as such -       std::ostringstream path;
      path << "D:/";
      _putenv_s("PYTHONPATH", path.str().c_str());

Comment: Did you mean: `from Cat import Cat`?

Comment: maybe a stupid question but does the script run successfully when you execute it from python (e.g. `python dog.py`) instead of running it through C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can import a python file and call a method with the following code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_SetProgramName(L"main");
    // Py_SetPythonHome(L"");
    // Py_SetPath(L"");

    // Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag = 1;
    // Py_DontWriteBytecodeFlag = 1;
    // Py_NoUserSiteDirectory = 1;
    Py_IsolatedFlag = 1;
    // Py_NoSiteFlag = 1;

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject * dog_module = PyImport_ImportModule("Dog");
    PyObject * dog = PyObject_CallMethod(dog_module, "Dog", NULL);
}
```

Use `Py_SetPythonHome` and `Py_SetPath` if needed.
Uncomment the flags you might need in the embedded environment.

- Docs for [initializing](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html)
- Docs for [import](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html?highlight=pyimport_#c.PyImport_ImportModule)
- Docs for [calling objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callmethod#c.PyObject_CallFunction) and [calling methods](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callmethod#c.PyObject_CallMethod)